# Sending values from discord.js to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
var ticketid;
ticketid = 0;

module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket',
    description: "ticket command",
    execute(message, args, client){
        ticketid = ticketid + 1;
        message.channel.send('we have sent you your personal ticket');
        message.author.send('here is your ticket, to redeem your ticket and get your server made you must DM BaysideGalaxy23#1219 your unique ticket. your ticket is: ' + ticketid);
        client.channels.cache.get('755222968287625287').send(ticketid);
    }
}
```

I have the variable ticketid and every time it is updated i want to send that new value to a JSON file. How do i do that?

Comment: You could check [fs' documentations](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) see if you have time to manipulate a json file !

Answer (score 1):

You could use Node.js's `fs` package to read and write the file.

First, you'll need to require it, and then, to read file you can use `readFileSync` and to write the file `writeFileSync`.

So assuming the JSON file you want to write is in on the root directory and is called 'tickets.json' you could do something like that:

```js
// Requiring FS
const fs = require('fs');

// TO READ
// Read the file and then parse the buffer to an actual Javascript object.
const data = fs.readFileSync('tickets.json');
const tickets = JSON.parse(data);

// TO WRITE
// JSON format the data and then write to the file
const dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(tickets, null, 2);
fs.writeFileSync('tickets.json', data);
```

You have to pass the absolute directory if the JSON file isn't in the root folder of the bot though. For this example, I'll presume it is on the same folder as the command.

So assuming what you want to do is store something like this (an array containing map-like arrays storing [ticket, userId]):

[image]

Your final command could look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  description: "ticket command",
  execute(message, args) {
    // Require fs and path (we will use path to handle the relative directory)
    // You could just use the absolute path instead if you feel like it
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    // Read the current tickets
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './tickets.json'));
    const tickets = JSON.parse(data);

    // Generate a new ticket and then push it to the tickets array
    const ticketId = (tickets[tickets.length - 1][0]) + 1;
    tickets.push([ticketId, message.author.id]);

    // Save the tickets with the newly created ticket
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './tickets.json'), JSON.stringify(tickets, null, 2));
    
    // Do your thing
    message.author.send(`Here is your ticket, to redeem your ticket and get your server made you must DM BaysideGalaxy23#1219 your unique ticket. Your ticket is: ${ticketId}`);
    message.channel.send(`We have sent you your personal ticket via DM.`);
    message.client.channels.cache.get('755222968287625287').send(`${ticketId} - ${message.author.toString()}`);
  }
}
```

**Notice that this example will only work if you have at least one ticket on the JSON File already, so mind that. Handle the exception or manually create the first ticket on the JSON file if you want to use this as a starting point.**

Here's more info on how to read and write JSON files in Node.js:
[Reading and Writing JSON Files with Node.js](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/)

Comment: To manually create the first ticket, you could just go on and write manually this to the JSON File: ```[ [1, "Random User ID"] ]```

Comment: I entered that into the json file and nothing happened when i ran the command in discord, no extra ticket was saved, do you mind helping, thanks. and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem. Any way you could share what was the problem so I could edit the answer to help other people that may come into this answer?

Comment: I just wrote the code a little wrong in the JSON file.